# GridSearchCV on a working pipeline returns ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am using GridSearchCV in order to find the best parameters for my pipeline.

My pipeline seems to work well as I can apply:

```
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

And I get a decent result.

But GridSearchCV obviously doesn't like something, and I cannot figure it out.

My pipeline:

```
feats = FeatureUnion([('age', age),
                      ('education_num', education_num),
                      ('is_education_favo', is_education_favo),
                      ('is_marital_status_favo', is_marital_status_favo),
                      ('hours_per_week', hours_per_week),
                      ('capital_diff', capital_diff),
                      ('sex', sex),
                      ('race', race),
                      ('native_country', native_country)
                     ])

pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('adhocFC',AdHocFeaturesCreation()),
        ('imputers', KnnImputer(target = 'native-country', n_neighbors = 5)),
        ('features',feats),('clf',LogisticRegression())])
```

My GridSearch:

```
hyperparameters = {'imputers__n_neighbors' : [5,21,41], 'clf__C' : [1.0, 2.0]}

GSCV = GridSearchCV(pipeline, hyperparameters, cv=3, scoring = 'roc_auc' , refit = False) #change n_jobs = 2, refit = False

GSCV.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I receive 11 similar warnings:

> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:11:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

and this is the error message:

> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:11:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:12:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:14:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3 GSCV = GridSearchCV(pipeline, hyperparameters, cv=3, scoring = 'roc_auc' ,refit = False) #change n_jobs = 2, refit = False
>         4 
>   ----> 5 GSCV.fit(X_train, y_train)
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py
>   in fit(self, X, y, groups)
>       943             train/test set.
>       944         """
>   --> 945         return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
>       946 
>       947
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py
>   in _fit(self, X, y, groups, parameter_iterable)
>       562                                   return_times=True, return_parameters=True,
>       563                                   error_score=self.error_score)
>   --> 564           for parameters in parameter_iterable
>       565           for train, test in cv_iter)
>       566
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py
>   in **call**(self, iterable)
>       756             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
>       757             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
>   --> 758             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
>       759                 self._iterating = True
>       760             else:
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py
>   in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
>       606                 return False
>       607             else:
>   --> 608                 self._dispatch(tasks)
>       609                 return True
>       610
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py
>   in _dispatch(self, batch)
>       569         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
>       570         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
>   --> 571         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
>       572         self._jobs.append(job)
>       573
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py
>   in apply_async(self, func, callback)
>       107     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
>       108         """Schedule a func to be run"""
>   --> 109         result = ImmediateResult(func)
>       110         if callback:
>       111             callback(result)
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py
>   in **init**(self, batch)
>       324         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
>       325         # arguments in memory
>   --> 326         self.results = batch()
>       327 
>       328     def get(self):
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py
>   in **call**(self)
>       129 
>       130     def **call**(self):
>   --> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
>       132 
>       133     def **len**(self):
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py
>   in (.0)
>       129 
>       130     def **call**(self):
>   --> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
>       132 
>       133     def **len**(self):
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py
>   in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose,
>   parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters,
>   return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
>       236             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
>       237         else:
>   --> 238             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
>       239 
>       240     except Exception as e:
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py
>   in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
>       266             This estimator
>       267         """
>   --> 268         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
>       269         if self._final_estimator is not None:
>       270             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py
>   in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
>       232                 pass
>       233             elif hasattr(transform, "fit_transform"):
>   --> 234                 Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name])
>       235             else:
>       236                 Xt = transform.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name]) \
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py
>   in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
>       495         else:
>       496             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
>   --> 497             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
>       498 
>       499
>
> in fit(self, X, y)
>        16         self.ohe.fit(X_full)
>        17         #Create a Dataframe that does not contain any nulls, categ variables are OHE, with all each rows
>   ---> 18         X_ohe_full = self.ohe.transform(X_full[~X[self.col].isnull()].drop(self.col,
>   axis=1))
>        19 
>        20         #Fit the classifier on lines where col is null
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py
>   in **getitem**(self, key)    2057             return
>   self._getitem_multilevel(key)    2058         else:
>   -> 2059             return self._getitem_column(key)    2060     2061     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py
>   in _getitem_column(self, key)    2064         # get column    2065
>   if self.columns.is_unique:
>   -> 2066             return self._get_item_cache(key)    2067     2068         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
>   in _get_item_cache(self, item)    1384         res = cache.get(item)
>   1385         if res is None:
>   -> 1386             values = self._data.get(item)    1387             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)    1388
>   cache[item] = res
>
> /home/jo/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
>   in get(self, item, fastpath)    3550                         loc =
>   indexer.item()    3551                     else:
>   -> 3552                         raise ValueError("cannot label index with a null key")    3553     3554             return self.iget(loc,
>   fastpath=fastpath)
>
> ValueError: cannot label index with a null key

Comment: Your definition of `hyperparameters` appears to be fine. Your instantiation of `GridSearchCV` looks correct. It seems like the problem could be connected to your data. How did you create `X_train`, `X_test` and `y_train`? Could you please post your full code for creating/importing the data and creating these 3 variables? That _might_ help offer some clues about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information I believe it is because your `X_train` and `y_train` variables are pandas dataframe, the basic sci-kit learn library isn't comparable with these: e.g., the [`.fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) method of a classifier is expecting an array like object.

By feeding in pandas dataframes you are inadvertently indexing them like numpy arrays, which is not that stable in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing).

Try converting your training data to numpy arrays:

```
X_train_arr = X_train.to_numpy()
y_train_arr = y_train.to_numpy()
```